# Must use import to load ES module: ...\node_modules\got\dist\source\index.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, node.js-got

There's dozens of other questions with basically the same title, but none of the answers seem to be relevant and just add to the confusion.

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2017", "es7", "es6", "dom"],
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

This is what I typed:

```
import md5 from 'js-md5';
import got from 'got';
import { Design } from './Design';
...
```

This is my error:

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\...\node_modules\got\dist\source\index.js
> require() of ES modules is not supported.

What. I'm *not* using `require`, I'm using `import`. I haven't had this error on any other modules, so why is Got different (and why is nothing ever simple)?

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

---

As per [@jsejcksn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71215905/2288578), I tried changing my `tsconfig.json` to the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2017", "es7", "es6", "dom"],
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

... and added `"type": "module"` to my `package.json`:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
        "got": "^12.0.1",
        "js-md5": "^0.7.3",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "semver": "^7.3.5",
        "typescript": "^4.4.3",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2",
        "@types/node": "^16.9.2",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
        "@types/fs-extra": "^9.0.13",
        "@types/semver": "^7.3.9",
        "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
        "@types/js-md5": "^0.4.3"
    },
    "type": "module"
}
```

But now I just get different errors :|

> src/Logging.ts:1:20 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'moment'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?
>
> 1 import moment from 'moment';
>
> src/SyncAPI.ts:2:17 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'got'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?
>
> 2 import got from 'got';

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have configured TypeScript to compile your modules to CommonJS format (your TSConfig option [`compilerOptions.module`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) is set to `"commonjs"`). You'll need to set that option to an ESM-compatible setting (such as `"esnext"`) so that the compiled JavaScript emitted by the TS compiler is in ESM format.

In your `package.json`, you'll probably also need to set [the `"type"` field](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#type) to `"module"`.

---

Edit: To use npm packages by name as bare specifiers in your import statements, you'll also need to update your TSConfig `compilerOptions.moduleResolution` to `"node"`. In your current config, you have included `"dom"` in the `compilerOptions.lib` array. `"dom"` is for environments with a DOM (which Node does not natively have), so that shouldn't be there. Instead, setting that array to `["es2017"]` will include the others you have specified.

---

Edit: In attempt to provide more direct guidance:

- Make sure you're not using an outdated version of Node (the current LTS is `^16.x.x`)
- Make sure you're not using an outdated version of TypeScript (currently at `^4.5.x`)
- Move all your source files to `./src` (if they're not already in that directory), and
- Use this as your `./tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2021"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2021"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

- and make sure that the "type" field in your `./package.json` is set to "module":

```jsonc
{
  // ...
  "type": "module"
  // ...
}
```

You shouldn't have any trouble with `import` statement module system compatibility after that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I don't have a clue what it means :| Changing `compilerOptions.module` to `esnext` makes new errors appear, and adding `"type": "module"` doesn't change anything. `Cannot find module 'moment'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node'` and the same thing for Got. I don't know anything about how importing modules actually works but this seems beyond excessively complicated.

Comment: Yes, setting `compilerOptions.moduleResolution` to `"node"` is required to use bare module specifiers (npm package imports). You'll want to spend some time learning about different JS module systems (ESM and CJS specifically), about how import specifiers work, about how TypeScript compiles TypeScript syntax to JavaScript syntax according to your configuration, about how Node interprets different syntax, etc. before you can expect to be productive.

Comment: If you are looking for a simpler tooling experience for your out-of-browser TypeScript programming, you might find [Deno](https://deno.land) of interest.

Comment: _"You'll want to spend some time learning..."_ sigh. My issue with this is I shouldn't have to. It should just work. Typescript, NodeJS, even Got... these have all been around for AGES and are massively popular. There's zero reason that I should have to understand how a compiler works to use it. I should just be able to follow the instructions and it should just work. I get really fed up with people saying "nah you have to know 13 years of history to understand how to use this". That's insane. `import got from 'got'` should work exactly the same as `import moment from 'moment'`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer though. Eventually I discovered that Got v11 works as expected. For clarification, my problem isn't just that it doesn't work, but also that it doesn't work and _doesn't tell you why_. The error is meaningless since I'm already using `import` rather than `require`. Suddenly I go from being nearly finished to wasting two hours trying to understand why it doesn't work when I'm doing exactly what it says to do and exactly what I have done for the past year with literally every other module. Makes it feel like Got is different for the sake of being different.

Comment: "_My issue with this is I shouldn't have to [spend time learning how to use the toolchain I'm trying to use]_"  That mentality might be part of the reason you're having trouble.

Comment: Perhaps, though I would argue very few people fully understand their toolchains. They just learn enough to get it working and then expect it to keep working. My complaint is more about how hidden the problem is. I've been using it for over a year with dozens of instances `import x from 'x'` and this is the first time I've seen this issue. That's really frustrating. I don't even remember why I set tsconfig the way I did let alone how it works. I just want it to continue functioning as it has. (Now I vaguely know the issue: there's a giant nightmare of different module systems under the hood.)

Comment: @Clonkex I updated my answer to provide some very direct guidance. Does that now answer your question?

Comment: Well, I tried. I used nvm-windows to update node to 16.14.0. I set my tsconfig and package.json as you said. I specified the latest 4.5 version of ts. But something about node 16 or npm 8 just doesn't play nice. Like, at all. I can't even do npm install. All it ever does is say `npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'`. So I tried reverting to node 14.15.4 and using that latest ts, but I just get `Cannot find module '...\dist\Design' imported from ...\dist\Server.js` for any of my own code. Unfortunately this is production software and I need it to just work, so I can't really mess with updates.

Comment: Ooo apparently it's a [bug in npm](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4234), huh. Well I'll come back to this when I have more time. Really under pressure to just get the software done right now.

Comment: Re: `nvm-windows`: I suggest looking at [`volta`](https://volta.sh/) when you get a chance.

Comment: The JS world is completely confusing. No normal person knows when/why to use which module type in which case. It's just so fragmented.

Answer (score 13):

In my case this very error was caused by `ts-node-dev` package.

If you use the same package (it usually sits in dev dependencies in `package.json`) you may check the resolution steps [I posted in a parallel thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74921691/11575732). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `tsc-node-esm` instead of `tsc-node` to run your script after adding `"type": "module"` to your `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up spending too much time trying to resolve a similar issue and decided to create a new file and just copy the source code of the library into  it and import it from there...

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours on this and searching a lot of questions, I finally found this little trick:

Add the following to `jest.config.ts` (or the `jest` section of your package.json):

```js
extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts']
```

Source: https://github.com/swc-project/jest/issues/102#issuecomment-1152957356

Comment: When I enable this, running the jest tests complains that nothing is exported from my TS files, like this: `SyntaxError: The requested module './embedding_vector' does not provide an export named 'embedding_vector'`

Comment: @vick Well, what are you exporting from that file? Sounds like a separate issue

Comment: I'm using `ts-jest` and needed to also add the option to it: `"useESM": true` then combined with this it started working. The amount of work to make jest work with TS is just way to much :(