# Error: Must use import to load ES Module - Using Typescript and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, chalk

**Background**

Tried to improve my error coding visibility and structure and decided to add the dependency ''' chalk ''', which requires Pure ESM. Originally, my ts.config/package.json was a common.js file and did not declare the "type" as "module". Made some changes as following chalk documentation and similar stack overflow troubleshooting. Upon reloading my app, I receive this error:

**Error**

```
[user] 
[user] > user@1.0.0 start
[user] > ts-node-dev src/index.ts
[user]
[user] [INFO] 02:43:13 ts-node-dev ver. 2.0.0 (using ts-node ver. 10.8.0, typescript ver. 4.7.2)
[user] Compilation error in /app/src/index.ts
[user] Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /app/src/index.ts
[user]     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/index.ts:1:7)
[user]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
[user]     at Module._compile (/app/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:568:25)
[user]     at Module.m._compile (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-07536074778072654.js:69:33)
[user]     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
[user]     at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-07536074778072654.js:114:20)
[user]     at require.extensions.<computed> (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-07536074778072654.js:71:20)
[user]     at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (/app/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:63:13)
[user]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
[user]     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
[user] [ERROR] 02:43:13 Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /app/src/index.ts
```

The following the changes I made to require requirements that I believe were neccessary?:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.8",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "chalk": "^5.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dependencies": "^0.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "joi": "^17.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.5",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import  app  from "./app";

const dbURI ='blabla' */
let PORT = 3000; /* process.env.PORT */

async function start() {

//T:              Connecting to MongoDB Database
    try{
        await mongoose
            .connect(dbURI)
            console.log(`connected to DB!`);        
    }catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    };
    app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log(
        `connected to PORT: ${PORT} and listening...although it may not bee that port`)
    });
}

start()
```

**ts.config**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "ESNext",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "ESNext",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
     "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,      /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
   "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

**Edit:File I called chalk in to test**

```
import express from "express";
import { NotFoundError } from "./errors/NotFoundError";
import errorHandler from "./middleware/error-handler";
import userIndex from "./routes/userIndex";
import morgan from "morgan"
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import chalk from 'chalk'



const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.set("trust proxy", true);

const log = console.log;


// I tried all methods below...
app.use(
    morgan(
    // "dev", 
    function (tokens, req, res) {
        return [
            chalk.red (tokens.method(req, res)),
            chalk.green(tokens.url(req, res)),
            chalk.yellow(tokens.status(req, res),"-"),
            chalk.bgBlueBright(tokens["response-time"](req, res), "ms"),
            chalk.cyan(tokens['date'](req, res),'web'),
            chalk.blue(tokens.res(req, res, "content-length")),
        ].join(" ");
    }) 
    ) 
    
log(chalk.red('I'm red'))
log(chalk.green(
    'I am a green line ' +
    chalk.blue.underline.bold('with a blue substring') +
    ' that becomes green again!'
));
log(chalk.rgb(123, 45, 67).underline('Underlined reddish color'));

    app.use(morgan( function (tokens, req, res) {
        return chalk.yellow(tokens['date'](req, res),'web')
        + ' ' + chalk.blue(tokens['remote-addr'](req, res))
        + ' ' + chalk.cyanBright(tokens.method(req, res))
        + ' ' + chalk.green(tokens.url(req, res))
        + ' ' + chalk.magentaBright(tokens.status(req, res))
        + ' ' + chalk.red(tokens['response-time'](req, res))
    }))


 app.use(morgan(`
:remote-addr :remote-user :method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms :date[web]
`)); 

app.use('/users', userIndex);

app.all("*", async (req, res, next) => {
    next(new NotFoundError());
});

app.use(errorHandler);

export default app ;
```

Comment: Where is the code where you try to import chalk?

Comment: I commented some deleted a /* somewhere above I shouldn't in the cut and paste above,  but basically tested some pasted clippets from the documentation individually to see if it worked. None did.

Comment: Sorry, could you also include the compiled JS file that called chalk in the TS?

Answer (score 17):

Seems that I have found a resolution after spending hours on that... I think it may help someone, as I've seen no such answer on Stackoverflow.

The problem was in `ts-node-dev`! No one would guess. But there is [an open bug](https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev/issues/314) on that in their repo. Of course it has nothing to do with `chalk`. And of course as the first step one needs to fix the project to work with ESM as described in many places (a good explanation sits in [chalk repo](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c)).

To check it is `ts-node-dev` problem you may simply run `tsc` (original TS compiler) from your project root. It didn't output this 'import' error for me, and after I fixed a few other errors it compiled everything successfully.

**Solution**

So I uninstalled `ts-node-dev` and installed `ts-node` and `nodemon` instead, as recommended [here](https://github.com/wclr/ts-node-dev/issues/314#issuecomment-1243067589).

First of all you may check the `ts-node` compilation and run attempt succeeds via:

```
node --loader ts-node/esm --inspect ./src/server.ts
```

Next, `nodemon` and `ts-node` should be run together to replace `ts-node-dev`:

From command line: `nodemon --exec node --loader ts-node/esm src/server.ts`

Or add it to `scripts` section in `package.json` (to use through `npm run dev`):

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "dev": "nodemon --exec node --loader ts-node/esm src/server.ts",
    ...
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

Just delete `type: 'module'` property from your package.json

It works for me.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, always the same everywhere - it "works" for you... löl

... exactly until you'll've to **resolve** it - just because `"type": "module"` is ***NOT*** something optional one can set as he wishes! 

Gruesome that such gets upvotes! 